# How does a spring converter get a transactional scope?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I was wondering, how a spring converter implementation gets an transactional scope.

Having a `Converter` which is used to convert a path placeholder (entity id) in an (rest) controller to the `Entity` itself. The `Entity` thus is loaded via Hibernate from the database.

For the details:

- spring boot 2.3.2
- A rest controller endpoint which triggers the converter to expand a path-placeholder (prior executing the rest-endpoint method body)
- If in question, the controller method is not annotated `@Transactional` either

**Question**:

How (since we disabled OSIV) does this `Converter` get it's `Transactional` scope if the convert neither the method/nor the converter class is annotated using `Transactional` nor the `convert` method does custom transaction handling?

Comment: If there is no transaction managed on application level then it relies on the resource level transaction means database local transaction for each request

Comment: If you mean how Spring Data repositories get a transaction, the answer is all repository methods are transactional by default

Comment: @crizzis could you offer your comment as an answer, i would accept it. you are perfectly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how Spring Data repositories get a transaction, the answer is all repository methods are transactional by default.